# Android viewpager, Cursorload and FragmentStatePagerAdapter - cannot goto previous items from the sected item

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cursorloader, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a Viewpager that uses a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and loads fragments with cursorloader. Everything is working fine but the problem is I cannot swipe the left(move backwards) from the item I selected from the listview.

Update:

[image]

The above picture clearly depicts the actual scenario of my usecase. When I click on 3rd item of listview the details will be appeared in fragment of viewpager in activity B. I can able swipe right to check further items in the list and go back to the item which I have selected but I cannot go back beyond 3rd item in viewpager.

Comment: listview? what listview?

Comment: If you click on the 2nd item, does it work? There's no code, so difficult it is, to diagnose the problem you have.

Comment: @ataulm Thanks for the response. Just I have updated my question. If I click on  the 2nd item, it works but in the viewpager I cannot go to the 1st item.

Comment: There's no code so it's difficult to diagnose. In Activity B, I would first check the `viewPagerAdapter.getCount()` to ensure it's what you expect. I suspect  it won't be, and it's only loading items from the point of click onwards.

Comment: @ataulm I am using the same code from this article http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/showcase/9/

Comment: @Ryan there's not enough information in the question you've posed to diagnose this. I'd recommend checking the count is what you expect (cursor and pager adapter), then you'll have more information with which to debug or ask a more detailed question.

Comment: @ataulm  I have updated my question with code also. Can you please have a look.

Comment: I've asked twice about the adapter count. Please try to find out - I cannot debug this by looking.

Comment: @ataulm I have 10 items in the list and the same count is coming everytime from getcount().

Comment: There is a list adapter, cursor and viewpageradapter. Are they all returning 10?

Comment: yes all these are returning 10

Comment: When you say you can't go back, do you mean you can swipe to the previous page but the data is not bound correctly to the page?

Comment: No I cannot swipe  to the previous pages.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. If the `ViewPager's` `PagerAdapter#getCount()` returns 10, there should be 10 navigable pages, regardless of the content.